# apply over rows and columns conditioned to the value of other matrix without a loop R

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to performed operations by element in a matrix if the values of other matrix meet some criteria. I know how to solve it with a `for` loop using rows and columns but I'm sure that there are more efficient ways to do it in R. I have tried with `apply(...,c(1,2),FUN)`but don't know how to go over the elements of `cond` to check its values:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(9),3,3)
cl <- c('a','b','c')
cond <- matrix(sample(cl,9,replace=T),3,3)
res.m <- apply(m, c(1,2), function(x) if (cond == 'a' ) { x*10 } if (cond == 'b' ) { x*-10 } else  { 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward way. Use a named vector to set your conditions.

First, here's the data I'm working with:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(rnorm(9),3,3)
cl <- c('a','b','c')
cond <- matrix(sample(cl,9,replace=T),3,3)
m
#            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291
# [2,]  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247
# [3,] -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814

cond
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "b"  "a"  "a" 
# [2,] "c"  "b"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "a"  "a"
```

Second, the solution in one nice compact line.

```
m * c(a = 10, b = -10, c = 0)[cond]
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 6.264538 15.952808  4.874291
# [2,] 0.000000 -3.295078 -7.383247
# [3,] 0.000000 -8.204684  5.757814
```

Basically, the `c(a = 10, b = -10, c = 0)[cond]` uses your "cond" matrix to create a vector that you can use to multiply your original matrix by.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
m[conda] <- m[conda <- cond == 'a'] * 10
m[condb] <- m[condb <- cond == 'b'] * -10
m[!conda & !condb] <- 0
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I get `Error: object 'conda' not found`. Ideas?